# Нужно ли ставить запятую после "ты думала"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли в этом предложении ставить запятую?

"Ты думала, там Вася?"

Если бы там было "что", то нужно, конечно, но тут что-то запутался.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно. "Ты думала, там Вася?"- сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, так бывает, что союз пропускается в живой речи.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Да всё правильно, сложноподчинённое предложение. Во втором опущено сказуемое, например, "находится".

Answer (score 0):

Очень бы хотелось считать это предложение СПП с пропущенным союзом, но мешает вопросительный знак, который ставится только в БСП.

А что если придать выражению "Ты думала" статус вводного предложения? Например: Там, ты думала, Вася?

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Данное предложение (с разными местоимениями)  может иметь  ТРИ РАЗНЫХ ВАРИАНТА: «Я (она) думала, что там Вася»(1). Это утверждение.  «Ты думала, что там Вася?»(2). Это вопрос к главному предложению. «Она думала: там Вася?» (3). Это вопрос к придаточной части.

С местоимением «ты»  более вероятен вариант 2, и тогда это СПП. БСП с «прямым вопросом» – это вариант 3, но здесь он, действительно, ВОЗМОЖЕН ЧИСТО ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИ (когда герой сам про себя рассуждает).

Немного о термине «ПРЯМОЙ ВОПРОС». К моему счастью, я не являюсь его автором. Его «придумали» раньше – Розенталь,  наверное.   Это в том случае, если правила вообще можно «придумывать». Думаю, что правила - это решение конкретных задач, выполненных в соответствии с орфографическими законами и орфографическим сводом 1956 года, которые мы рассматриваем в качестве общепринятого образца.

А теперь о самом «прямом вопросе». Если вторая часть предложения  является вопросительной, то  ее можно оформить с помощью косвенной речи как СПП или в виде БСП с «прямым вопросом» (вопросительная интонация и вопросительный знак в конце предложения), например: Я спрашивал  себя: так ли хороша моя жизнь? Я размышлял, так ли хороша моя жизнь.

Comment: Интересная мысль насчет вводной конструкции, ведь предложение можно представить и так: "По-твоему, там Вася?"

Comment: А следующее моё предложение не СПП ? С чего это Вы взяли, что  СПП не может быть вопросительным?  А вот это: Ты знаешь о том, что вопросительным может быть любое предложение - и простое, и БСП, и СПП? Зачем придумывать новые правила: "мешает вопросительный знак, который ставится только в БСП".